# How to install 3rd party Python libraries for a single script running on AWS EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nltk

I have a script that uses the [nltk python library](https://github.com/nltk/nltk). I'm just trying to wrap my head around how one would install this library and potentially other libraries as well on AWS/EC2. This is a standalone script.

I figured it might be done with the [aws cli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) but the documentation on Amazon seems to be lacking a bit.

Can someone help a complete Python newb with some Python and AWS?!?! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you fire up an AWS instance you select an "Image".

These are called [Amazon Machine Images](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) or **AMI** for short.

Typically you would select say (*for example*) an "Ubuntu" AMI.

Example: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

Select the appropriate AMI and then perform some steps similar to:

1. Configure and Start your Instance
2. Shell into your Instance
3. Run: `apt-get install python-setuptools`
4. Run: `easy_install nltk`

You **may** also find the Python package(s) you're looking for already available in the repositories of the Distribution/Image you've selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I used:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
# Then use pip to install 3rd party libraries
pip install selenium
# works now
```

I did as this article points: also using Ubuntu

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html